# PHP SQL QUERY - Filtering with Query, multiple values for item

Tags: php, mysql, json

I  have been learning PHP/MySQL for some time, have not learned that much, as I am focusing on iPhone Development as well as tackling my full time job as well.

I am building a mesaging client, using JSON to pull new messages and a chat windows....  The part I am having ap roblem with is  getting information from my database.  I am loking in this request to get all messages betwen to people (IE: FromUser and ToUser) and then display them in JSON, however I cannot display it in JSON properly for some reason.

Here is my example

```
<?php 
 $enduser = $_GET['usernameto'];
$enduser1 = $_GET['usernamefrom'];
$db = mydatabase;
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","password");
if (!$con)
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
   $arr = array();
       //Execute the query
      $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE touser = '$enduser' AND fromuser = '$enduser1'");
        $rs1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE touser = '$enduser1' AND fromuser = '$enduser'");

        // Add the rows to the array 
       while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
        $arr = $obj;
        } 

    // Add the rows to the array 
   while($obj1 = mysql_fetch_object($rs1)) {
   $arr1 = $obj1;
   }

  echo '{"users":'.json_encode($arr).' '.json_encode($arr1).'}';
// echo ''.json_encode($arr).'';
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Now this does show all messages for example  FromUser= user1 ToUser= user2  and shows also  Fromuser= user2 and toUser = User1.      in two seperate JSON lists, but I would like for them to be pulled on one simple JSON list, if that can be done, that would be amazing, I know it must lay in my query section...

I also know their is tons of vulnerabilities and issues with my code that are not "clean" however for the time been this doesn't need to follow those methods, until I go and learn how to follow SQLi and Real Escape strings/injections....

Thanks :-)

Comment: No. you don't learn about sql and escaping and injections "later". You learn it **NOW**. You're proposing to go race in a Formula 1 car before you've even learned to crawl.

Comment: I agree. SQLi/XSS/CRSF vulnerabilities aren't to be taken lightly.

Answer (score 0):

The comment about learning about SQL Injection is correct but you would be able to get the messages in one query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (touser = '$enduser' AND fromuser = '$enduser1') OR (touser = '$enduser1' AND fromuser = '$enduser')
```

This should select what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unfocussed, but I think you just need to either  concatenate the two result arrays with

```
$combined = array_merge($arr, $arr1);
```

Or change your query so it pulls both sets of data at once.  But as Marc B say, you really need to get into the habit of avoid SQL injection, it's easy.